# Why my component in Angular doesn't display?

Tags: angular, components

I try to learn Angular Animation from : https://angular.io/guide/animations. I think I have follow corretly the steps and my component  doesn't display.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularAnimation</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**app.component.html**

```
<p>YES</p>
<app-open-close></app-open-close>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { OpenCloseComponent } from './open-close/open-close.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    OpenCloseComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'AngularAnimation';
}
```

---

**open-close.component.html**

```
<p>open-close work!</p>
<div [@openClose] = "isOpen ? 'open' : 'closed'" class="open-close-containter" >
    <p>The box is now {{ isOpen ? 'Open' : 'Closed' }}! </p>
</div>
```

**open-close.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-open-close',
  templateUrl: './open-close.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./open-close.component.scss'],
  animations:[
    trigger('openClose' , [
      state('open' , style ({
        height: '200px',
        opacity: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
      })),
      state('closed',style({
        height: '100px',
        opacity: 0.5,
        backgroundColor:'green',
      })),
      transition('open => closed' , [animate('1s')]),
      transition( 'closed => open' , [ animate('0.5s')]),
    ]),
  ]
})

export class OpenCloseComponent implements OnInit {

  isOpen = true;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  toggle(){
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }
}
```

My project :
[project tree structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZky9.png)

It displays me correctly YES from **app.component.html** but not the rest.

Thank's,

BOSS_ladis

Comment: Could it be the `heioght` instead of `height` in the closed animation state style object?

Comment: Thank's for your answer, it work !
Sorry for the inattention of this mistake --'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`heioght: '100px'` needs to be `height: '100px'`